# PHP XPath get Node by Attribute

Tags: php, xpath, attributes

I have a bookCatalog.xml file as below

```
<bookCatalog>
    <book id='1'>
        <title>html</title>
    </book>
    <book id='2'>
        <title>java</title>
    </book>
    <book id='3'>
        <title>php</title>
    </book>
</bookCatalog>
```

I want to **programmatically** get **the title value of a book node** by using variable **$id** of book node, and i used the following code:

```
    $doc=new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('bookCatalog.xml');
    $xpath= new DOMXPath($doc);       
    $findBookNode=$xpath->query("//book[@id='$id']")->item(0);

     foreach ($findBookNode as $child) {
            if ($child->nodeName === 'title') {
                $bookTitle = $child->nodeValue;                   
            }
        }
```

But it turned out that the result is not what i want.

If I **replace** the variable **$id** to **'1'**  , I can get **the title value** of the book node whose **id=1**;

```
 $findBookNode=$xpath->query("//book[@id='1']")->item(0);
```

Comment: where do you give values to $id paramater?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem in my code:

The problem is that the variable $id is assigned by $_POST['id'] from a form in another code segment.

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

Then the value of variable $id has **trailing space**, for example 
$id='1' 
become 
$id='1 ' // **one space after number 1**

Comment: Glad you found it. I've removed my answer, which assumed things from your Q. that were not visible in it. You can accept your own answer in a few days, I believe.